# Turn off the WAL file mode in RestKit Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, restkit-0.20

What is the magic combination of options to send to the sqlite to completely turn off journaling.

I have an initialization on install that brings down a lot of data. I don’t need journaling at this point
and it balloons the memory storage upon install to over 500MB!

I have tried:

```
var options = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true
options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_mode" : "TRUNCATE”]
```

or

```
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_mode" : “OFF"]
```

or

```
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_mode" : “DELETE”]
```

and

```
options[NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption] = true
```

even

```
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_size_limit" : "20000”]
```

by :

```
do {
                    _ = try
                        self.managedObjectStore!.addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath(storePath, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: nil, withConfiguration: nil, options: options)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("fail to add persistent store")
                    print(error)
                }
```

Nothing seems to allow me to turn this off completely. The WAL file always grows.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there just a small correction

```
var options = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
   options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = true  
options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = true 
options ["journal_mode" ] = "DELETE”
```